# TimeSpan not calculating

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to calculate create a time remaining calculator in VB.NET and it won't let me and I can't seem to figure out why. Here is my code

```
    Dim PrefendinedDateTime As DateTime = "3:00:00"
    Dim TimeNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim ElapsedTime As TimeSpan = (TimeNow - frmStartDateTime)

    Dim TimeRemaining As TimeSpan = PrefendinedDateTime - New DateTime(ElapsedTime.Ticks)

    txtTimeRemaining.Text = New DateTime(TimeRemaining.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

I get this error message:

Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.
Parameter name: ticks

Not quite sure what this means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a timespan to a date, because those are different ticks. What you need is this:

```
txtTimeRemaining.Text = TimeRemaining.ToString("g")
```

or this:

```
txtTimeRemaining.Text = TimeRemaining.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
```

Notice how format string is different for TimeSpan, compared to formatting a date time, for example, and that `:` now requires escaping. This is explained in detail in below link #2.

References:

- [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Let's stop here for a second, while I try to explain why it did not work for you. Forget about ticks, think in seconds, because it's a measurable interval, that's easy to get a grasp on. Suppose you time interval is a second. Now you are trying to create a date, passing one second into it. What do you expect to get? 1 second AD, i.e. 1st year, 1st month etc.? Fair enough.

Suppose now you have an interval of minus 1 second (yes, intervals can be negative). You would think it's 1 second BC, right? Unfortunately, negative dates in .NET are not allowed.

As a general rule of thumb, intervals of time (represented in .NET by a `TimeSpan`), and points in time (represented by a `DateTime`) should be treated separately, because they are logically different entities. There is one-way relation though, i.e. two dates can represent a TimeSpan. However, a TimeSpan does not represent two dates. In fact, no matter how many TimeSpans you have, you will never be able to relate them to any point in time.

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns:

Input string was not in a correct format. @Neolisk

Comment: I can understand that however I don't know how you would go about fixing this.

Comment: @user2177940: Try `TimeRemaining.ToString("g")` for now. I'll see if it supports custom formatting.

Comment: I think I've fixed it, there was a problem with my Initial DateTime. thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2177940: Yes, custom format strings are supported. This works: `hh\:mm\:ss`.